# how to enable youtube or vimeo embed in ckeditor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I am using [CKEditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem for rich textarea in my rails application. Now I want to attach YouTube or Vimeo videos and upload video from local file system function in ckeditor but I can't find any solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: May be this links will help you.. http://ckeditor.com/addon/mediaembed
http://riseofthephx.com/2010/10/13/adding-vimeoyoutube-iframe-embed-to-ckeditor/

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506457/ckeditor-youtube-plugin

Comment: its not duplicated, I am looking this for ruby on rails

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how do i add this add-on to my ckeditor gem ???

Comment: go through the readme.txt file of the downloaded zip folder

Comment: The second link you provided leads to a compromised website.

Answer (score 0):

for solve this task i'm added into toolbar 'Iframe' button
config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.toolbar_Easy =
  [
    ...
    {name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'Iframe' ] }
    ...
  ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Mediaembed plugin for ckeditor you may encounter a problem when inserting XSS blocking of media content and iframes on webkit. On my project we inserted type urls `[youtube url = "% url%"]` by the plugin, and then parsed them on the backend to generate a page.